# advantage of mounting a drive

Tags: linux, mount, smb

What is the advantage of mounting a drive using

```
mount -t cifs 192.168.1.10/Folder /mnt/folder
```

compared to accessing it directly through

```
smb://192.168.1.10/Folder
```

Comment: Both involve mounting it (since that is required regardless), the second simply makes it transparent.

Comment: That's not true – `smb://` in graphical file managers _does not_ result in a kernel cifs mount, it uses userspace libsmbclient.

Answer (score 0):

Because then the low level VFS is aware of the file system. Try running `ls smb://192.168.1.10/Folder` and see if it works ;3

Consequently using libsmbclient means you can talk to a SMB share without mounting it and by using technologies like KIO on KDE this also allows integration of the smb client into the file manager providing seamless management.

The same concept applies to FTP servers in web browsers. Although ironically KIO also provides ftp://. But that example illustrates how application level access to a protocol was a more pronounced difference than system level. Now they are fairly seamless from the users perspective.

Comment: How does this relate to permissions? Are permissions set when copying a file using libsmbclient?